# How to convert the OrderedDict to the normal dict but keep the same order as the OrderedDict?

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary

When I use the `dict()` the order is changed! How to get the dict follow the order of  `OrderedDict()`?

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> OrderedDict([('method', 'constant'), ('data', '1.225')])
OrderedDict([('method', 'constant'), ('data', '1.225')])
>>> dict(OrderedDict([('method', 'constant'), ('data', '1.225')]))
{'data': '1.225', 'method': 'constant'}
>>>
```

What I would like to get is the same order as `OrderedDict()`:

```
{'method': 'constant','data': '1.225'}
```

If cannot convert, how to parse the `OrderedDict` such as

```
for key, value in OrderedDict....
```

Comment: You can't. That's why you need to use an OrderedDict in the first place.

Comment: you can't. if you want put element in order, use list or tuple

Comment: By definition a (normal) dictionary does not have any order.  In any situation where a dictionary may appear to have any order, that is merely an unintended consequence of it's implementation and cannot be relied upon.  This is not just in python, but just about any other language that implements dictionaries.

Comment: @SonofaBeach until py3.6... `dict`'s in CPython become ordered.

Comment: @AChampion Yes, but one should also note that it is simply an implementation detail. It should not be relied upon, and could change in the future.

Comment: `collections.OrderedDict` has all the same behaviors as a `dict` - `for key, value in OrderedDict.items()....` is valid.

Comment: @SonofaBeach agreed, don't rely on it... sorry was meant more tongue-in-cheek to your sweeping assertion :)

Comment: @AChampion no worries.  I learned something, anyhow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to print out `dict` in order without the `OrderedDict` wrapper you can use `json`:

```
>>> import json
>>> od = OrderedDict([('method', 'constant'), ('data', '1.225')])
>>> print(json.dumps(od))
{"method": "constant", "data": "1.225"}
```

You can iterate an `OrderedDict` identically to a `dict`:

```
>>> for k, v in od.items():
...    print(k, v)
method constant
data 1.225
```